# How to use Pusher to send notification at specific time?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

Ok, I have a Laravel project (PHP and JS), and there is a counter on some page. 
Also I have a record in the database ["user_id" | "12/24/2019 - 18:00"]

My question is, how to push notification at 18:00 to start a counter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you need Pusher for this? When the page is loaded, just dump upcoming events into the HTML and use `setTimeout()` / `setInterval()` to handle the counter.

Comment: It is very unreliable and unprecious, also user can change values..